# Django (2.0.1) Row SQL Query - Putting Results into Templates Html *Raw query must include the primary key*

Tags: django, templates, rawsql

I am trying to fetch data from my database and displaying the results in a template. However, the results are not displayed. Result on the website is: "Raw query must include the primary key". This is my code:

**This is my code in the view:**

> ```
> class EventListView(ListView):
>
>     context_object_name = "events"
>     template_name = 'core/event_detail_list.html'
>
>     def get_queryset(self):
>         queryset =  Event.objects.raw("""select name, date from classroom_event""")
>         return queryset
> ```

**This is my code in template(event_detail_list.html):**

> ```
> {% extends 'base.html' %}
>
> {% block content %}
>
> <tbody>
>   {% for event in queryset %}
>     <tr>
>       <td class="align-middle">{{ event.name }}</td>
>       <td class="align-middle">{{ event.date }}</td>
>     </tr>
>   {% empty %}
>     <tr>
>       <td class="bg-light text-center font-italic" colspan="5">You haven't created any events yet.</td>
>     </tr>
>   {% endfor %}
> </tbody>
>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

**My Model looks the following:**

> ```
> class Event(models.Model):
>     owner_events = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='events')
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
>     date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
>
>     def get_absolute_url(self): # defekt
>         return reverse('event_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
>         return self.name
>
>     def get_event(self):
>         name = escape(self.name)
>         date =  escape(self.date)
>         return "Name: " + str(name) + " Datum: " + str(date)
>
> class User(AbstractUser):
>     is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
>     is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
>
> class Teacher(models.Model):
>     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
>     interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_teachers')
>     events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, related_name="teacher_events")
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.user.username
>
>     def get_events(self):
>         return "Name: " + str(self.events.name) + "Datum: "
>
>     def get_events_adr(self):
>         return self.events
>
>     def get_interests(self):
>         return "Interests: " + str(self.interests.name)
>
> class Student(models.Model):
>     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
>     quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')
>     interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_students')
>     events = models.ManyToManyField(Event, related_name="student_events")
>
>     def get_unanswered_questions(self, quiz):
>         answered_questions = self.quiz_answers \
>             .filter(answer__question__quiz=quiz) \
>             .values_list('answer__question__pk', flat=True)
>         questions = quiz.questions.exclude(pk__in=answered_questions).order_by('text')
>         return questions
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self.user.usernames
> ```

The event table looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL54h.png)

**Does anyone know, how to display the queryset-result into the template?**

Comment: And why you can't just add `id` to select query?

Comment: Lovely. It worked. Thanks a lot!